# Can I modify a layer which is uploaded by myself?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I first uploaded a GeoJSON type polygon to the OpenLayers. Can I still edit the feature of this layer? Here is the code I am using: (It can upload the GeoJSON layer but can not edit it)

```
        var map, layer;
        function init(){
        map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map');
        layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( "Simple OSM Map");
        map.addLayer(layer);
        map.setCenter(           
        new OpenLayers.LonLat(0.8,52.472).transform(
                new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                map.getProjectionObject()
            ), 7
        );
        var featurecollection = {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-248052.78111938,6928922.6476283],[-193018.12076172,6933661.7433813],[-167335.27926147,6885812.1636815],[-184915.79576462,6855084.4783151],[-228484.9018811,6854931.6042586],[-260588.45375641,6872512.1207617],[-266703.41601837,6898194.962262],[-248052.78111938,6928922.6476283]]]};
        var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
        var vector_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector({
          projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
        }); 
        map.addLayer(vector_layer);
        vector_layer.addFeatures geojson_format.read(featurecollection));
        //Until Here, No Problem   
        var select_control = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vector_layer);
        select_control.activate();  
        var modify_control = new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(vector_layer,{
            mode:OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.RESHAPE
        });
        map.addControl(modify_control);
        modify_control.activate();
    }
```

Is there something wrong with the editing code?

Comment: Still need an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have a select control and a modify control activated at the same time, The modify control has it's own select mechanism, so there's no need for a select control (and if you do need it, deactivate it when activating the modify control. A [Panel](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/Panel-js.html) might simplify that).

See http://jsfiddle.net/MGHFu/ for what is needed to get your code working.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I ask one more question to you: After the modification, how can I save the new feature as the geojson data? Thanks a lot.

Comment: sure: listen to the "afterfeaturemodified" event on the layer, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/2VUX3/4/ and then use your favorite method to POST/PUT to server

Comment: Thanks Altefren. You know, I am still a student, could you give me more advice on this field. I am feeling that OpenLayers API documentation seems a little bit confusion to me since it doesn't have a relevant example on each command. Do you know how can I learn it fast. Thanks

Comment: I strongly advise you to read up on javascript, and study the source code of Openlayers. I'm not sure what you mean by fast, but what I do know (from personal expirience)  is that it takes time to learn to write code.